# Why some characters are replaced by apostrophe by native English writers?

Tags: spelling, apostrophe

I see words like

> stayin' , livin' , 'eck , 'our.

The first word I saw in the song, *Staying alive*.

Comment: What are *'eck* and *'our* supposed to mean, according to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen *'eck* or *'our* to be fair, but *stayin'* and *livin'* are informal writings born from [relaxed pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxed_pronunciation) and the tendency to want to write things the same way we hear them (especially these last 15 years).

This is the same phenomenon behind the apparition of *gonna*, *gotta*, *wanna*, *kinda*, *lemme* in written discussions: these are not grammatically acceptable but can be used in very informal discussions.

Comment: If you've never seen (or heard) [**Flippin 'eck!**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22flippin+eck%22), perhaps you're not the best person to be posting an answer here! :) Seriously, I'm guessing euphemistic *Heck = **Hell*** is primarily a BrE usage (it's certainly quite natural to me, and to be honest I think *enunciating* that /h/ would be less common than dropping it, Cockney or not).

Answer (score 1):

Similarly

> 'eck , 'our.

are used by native English **writers** (i.e. in literature) to imitate certain local accents (in Britain), where people tend not to pronounce the starting 'h' in words at all.